# Adobe DTM Selector Chain Not Working?

Tags: javascript, css, html, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to get the routing number using a data element from the code below using a CSS Selector chain and I don't know why I can't pick up the text (routing number) using a CSS Selector chain for the following code:

```
<table class="rich-table home table" id="startForm:PendingReviewApps" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><colgroup span="0"></colgroup><thead class="rich-table-thead"><tr class="rich-table-header  "><th class="rich-table-headercell  " scope="colgroup">Accounts Being Reviewed</th></tr></thead><tbody id="startForm:PendingReviewApps:tb"><tr class="rich-table-row rich-table-firstrow "><td class="rich-table-cell " id="startForm:PendingReviewApps:0:ProductSummaryForDepositApplicationId" style="width:80%"><span id="startForm:PendingReviewApps:0:ProductLabelForDepositAppId" style="font-size:14pt;">Easy Checking</span>
    <br />
    <p style="padding-left: 20px"><span id="startForm:PendingReviewApps:0:routingNumberSpan">
    Routing number:<span id="startForm:PendingReviewApps:0:RountingNumberForDepositAppId" style="font-weight:bold;">  121100782</span>
            <br /></span><span id="startForm:PendingReviewApps:0:intFundingAmtSpan">
        Initial funding amount: $<span id="startForm:PendingReviewApps:0:InitialFundingAmountForDepositAppId" style="font-weight:bold;">100.00</span>
            <br /></span>
    </p></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I've tried all types of combos but the tool I'm using (Adobe DTM)  is not returning the text value (routing number)? Attached is the CSS Selector chain results I see in the dev. console of Chrome but have had no luck using! I've tried the following:

```
span#startForm:PendingReviewApps:0:RountingNumberForDepositAppId
p #startForm:PendingReviewApps:0:RountingNumberForDepositAppId
```

But had no luck?

Here is the data element [image: Screenshot of Data Element]

and here is a screenshot of the Chrome Dev. Console showing the CSS Selector path:[image: Dev. Console Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

**(single) escape the colons**

`span#startForm\:PendingReviewApps\:0\:RountingNumberForDe‌​positAppId`

Ultimately DTM makes a [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) call, passing your value as the argument.

In this case, even though a colon `:` is a valid id character, it marks a [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) in css syntax, so you must escape it.

Meanwhile, `document.querySelector()` takes a string argument, and backslash is a special character to strings, so you must escape the escape (so overall `\\:`).

However, DTM automatically escapes backslashes, so you should only escape it *once* in the Data Element field, and the final evaluated value will be the double escaped `\\:`

**Use Attribute syntax**

`span[id="startForm:PendingReviewApps:0:RountingNumberForDepo‌​sitAppId"]`

This is an alternate selector using [Attribute syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). No real benefit to this vs. first method except that you don't have to worry about escaping the colons.

Comment: I tried both methods you described but I'm still not getting anything returned by my data element, only an empty string?

Comment: If I use span#startForm\:PendingReviewApps\:0\:routingNumberSpan (one level up) it returns "Routing number: 121100782" which I can work with. Must be something weird with the way the page is constructed?!?!

Comment: you know one thing i noticed when trying it in my sandbox, I copy/pasted what you had above and DTM kept storing part of the value as a unicode escaped value. Something like `startForm:PendingReviewApps:0:RountingNumberForDe\u1234positAppId` (I don't remember offhand what the unicode # was) which was kinda weird, so I manually typed it out when testing.  So you may wanna check if your selector (or your html code) is using unicode encoded chars